# How to build and host a jsreport server on IIS

Tags: report, jsreport

I have created a jsreport server with the free license and its working fine in the development mode. How can I build it to deploy in a IIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it following these steps. However, I don't recommend running jsreport through IIS and recommend to use windows service instead. See below.

1. remove `httpPort` property from the `jsreport.config.json`
2. download and place sample [web.config](https://github.com/jsreport/docs/blob/master/installation/web.config) into jsreport app folder
3. install [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) Don't forget to have iis installed with all Application development sub features and also iis url rewrite extension.
4. create standard iis website for jsreport folder and choose port and bindings you want, also don't forget to add security permissions to jsreport folder for IIS App Pool user when appropriate. IMPORTANT: Create a separate website. Don't just add application to the default website.
5. try access website url in browser, jsreport should pop up

However, we recommend using windows service instead of the IIS on windows servers.
https://jsreport.net/learn/windows

```sh
# install jsreport
mkdir jsreportapp
cd jsreportapp
npm i -g jsreport-cli
jsreport init
jsreport configure

# install service
jsreport win-install
```